# Spring Integration nioLocker Exception when reading

Tags: java, synchronization, spring-integration, file-locking

I have an integration flow that scans for files for processing. Since there might be multiple processors scanning the same directory, I added ".nioLocker()" to prevent processors from other JVMs from processing the file.

Here's the flow configuration:

```
IntegrationFlows.from( // Scan files from input dir
                    s -> s.file(new File(fileInputDir))
                            .preventDuplicates(true)
                            .nioLocker()
                            .regexFilter("(.)*\\.[xX][mM][lL]|(.)+\\.[dD][nN][eE]"),        // to match any case of the letters XML
                    p -> p.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(filePollerInterval)
                            .taskExecutor(new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(filePoolSize))
                    )
```

Now, the problem is that even with one processor running when I call BufferedReader.readLine, I get an exception stating that the file is locked

```
java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
```

I tried to release the lock by calling

```
 private NioFileLocker fileLocker = new NioFileLocker();
 fileLocker.unlock(file);
```

But that doesn't work! (I suspect because it's called from a different thread than that of the locker but I am not sure)

What is the proper way to obtain the lock? Is there a better way to ensure that only one processor obtains access to a resource?

----------------------------EDIT---------------------------------

So I went an extra step to make sure that the thread locking the file is the same as the thread that reads from its file channel. For this I used Direct Channels. (before, the message passed to the fileSplitter was through a QueueChannel which would execute a send() on a different thread). Still I get the error

```
2017-07-21 11:22:03.316  INFO 336488 --- [           main] c.f.e.m.i.MailerInboundApplication       : Started MailerInboundApplication in 13.541 seconds (JVM running for 14.419)
2017-07-21 11:22:09.946  INFO 336488 --- [ask-scheduler-5] o.s.i.file.FileReadingMessageSource      : Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=input\EMAIL92770.9352177.20170617.xml, headers={id=5dba6d62-b0a5-508e-48a9-cfddfa3b331f, timestamp=1500654129946}]]

2017-07-21 11:22:09.962 DEBUG 336488 --- [ask-scheduler-5] c.f.edd.mailer.inbound.core.FileRouter   : fileRouter received message: GenericMessage [payload=input\EMAIL92770.9352177.20170617.xml, headers={CORRELATION_ID=92770.9352177.20170617, id=32a8846d-5425-0b
ee-657e-8767e1fb6105, timestamp=1500654129962}]
2017-07-21 11:22:09.962 DEBUG 336488 --- [ask-scheduler-5] c.f.e.mailer.inbound.core.FileSplitter   : fileSplitter received message: GenericMessage [payload=input\EMAIL92770.9352177.20170617.xml, headers={CORRELATION_ID=92770.9352177.20170617, id=32a8846d-5425-
0bee-657e-8767e1fb6105, timestamp=1500654129962}]

java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read(FileDispatcherImpl.java:61)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:159)
        at com.fiserv.edd.mailer.inbound.core.FileSplitter.splitMessage(FileSplitter.java:93)
```

The code at FileSplitter.java:

```
    @Override
protected Object splitMessage(Message<?> message) {
    String correlationId = (String) message.getHeaders().get("CORRELATION_ID"); //Save the correlation ID so we can use it to send the DNE/CLP file later
    File file = (File) message.getPayload();
    String inputFileName = file.getName();


    log.info(LogEvent.getBuilder().withMessageId(inputFileName)
            .withMessage("Processing file: " + inputFileName).build());

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Optional<InputHeader> inputHeader = Optional.empty();// headerParser.parse(file);

    ParsingReport pr = new ParsingReport(inputFileName);
    try (RandomAccessFile lfs = new RandomAccessFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), "rw")){
        FileChannel fc = lfs.getChannel();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        fc.read(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
        System.out.println(new String(bytes));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Comment: Check here, please https://github.com/artembilan/spring-integration/commit/fe5d20e3650cc147d0e13af909347d0c2eb65279. The main trick that you can get access to the content of locked file only via `FileChannel` from that lock

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Thanks. The problem now becomes how do I meet the expectation of some class interface that reads from java.io.File or InputStream. It seems that I have to implement an InputStream with the read method implementing the "FileChannel reading code". Is this  recommended?

Comment: Sounds good. Sorry, I didn't dig so far in the subject.

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Accessing the content of a file is only allowed through the same thread that locked it. Do the components of a workflow execute on the same thread? In other words, if my flow consists of an sftp adapter with nioFilelocker that passes a message with the file as payload, to a file splitter who need access to it, shouldn't the file splitter execute on the same thread as the locker so it can access the content?

Comment: If you don't do that explicitly, everything is invoked on the same thread

Comment: @ArtemBilan: I made sure that the FileReadingMessageSource is on the same thread as the Reader (fileSplitter). Still no luck reading from the file's channel. I added the details in the question

Comment: Would be great to see your code in the `com.fiserv.edd.mailer.inbound.core.FileSplitter.splitMessage()`

Comment: @ArtemBilan: The code was added. Thanks for checking

Comment: OK. I see. One more time: The main trick that you can get access to the content of locked file only via `FileChannel` from that lock. So, you should perform `FileChannelCache.tryLockFor(file).channel()`. A new `lfs.getChannel()` really says that you can't do that.

Comment: @ArtemBilan: FileChannelCache is declared as "final class" so it can't be accessed outside its package. Which means that I can't do "Field channelCacheField = FileChannelCache.class.getDeclaredField("channelCache");" Moreover, NioFileLocker doesn't give access to the cache or the locks from that cache.

Comment: Oh! I see. Sorry, I did my sample in the same package :-). So, try this `new DirectFieldAccessor(nioFileLocker).getPropertyValue("lockCache")` and cast it into the `ConcurrentMap<File, FileLock>`. Meanwhile, please, raise a JIRA on the matter. This `NioFileLocker` causes a lot of problems. Should be revised somehow. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use `java.nio.channels.FileLock`, we can get access to file content only via `FileChannel` or `InputStream` associated with that lock:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
try {
    java.nio.channels.FileLock lock = in.getChannel().lock();
    try {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, charset);
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.release();
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

The `NioFileLocker` doesn't let to get access to the `FileLock` easily.
So, you should use in your code something like this:

```
 new DirectFieldAccessor(this.nioFileLocker).getPropertyValue("lockCac‌​he");
```

and cast it into the `Map<File, FileLock>` to be able to get a `FileLock` created for the file.

Meanwhile, please, raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter. This NioFileLocker causes a lot of problems. Should be revised somehow. Thanks

Comment: follow up: I found that it's better to avoid using Nio File locking and rely on Integration components to distribute the work. I managed to pipe the messages coming out of my FileReadingMessageSource to a RabitMQ first. Then processors running on different JVMs can each pick up a unique file from the queue. 
I wonder if there is a better way in Integration.

Comment: Distributed `MetadataStore` for the `FileSystemMarkerFilePresentFileListFilter`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store