# Spring integration: inbound channel with NioFileLocker leads to exception on read-only File System

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Versions:

```
Spring: 5.2.16.RELEASE
Spring Integrations: 5.3.9.RELEASE
Ubuntu: focal [20.04.3 LTS]
Java (build and runtime): 11
```

See stack trace pasted below.  My inbound channel is defined like this:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="channelIn" directory="${channel.dir}" auto-create-directory="false" use-watch-service="true" filter="channelFilter" watch-events="CREATE,MODIFY">
  <int-file:locker ref="channelLocker"/>
  <int:poller fixed-delay="${channel.polling.delay}" max-messages-per-poll="${channel.polling.maxmsgs}"></int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

with

```
<bean id="channelLocker" class="org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker"/>
```

My `ServiceActivator` logic looks like this:

```
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("channelLocker")
  private NioFileLocker nioFileLocker;

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channelIn")
  public void processResultsFile(File results)
  {
    if (!results.exists() || !results.isFile()) {
      logger.error("could not process invalid file {}", results.getAbsolutePath());
      return;
    }

    try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(results))) {
      // Process input stream ...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error("could not process file {}", results.getAbsolutePath(), ex);
    }

    nioFileLocker.unlock(results);
  }
```

[One article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179246/spring-integration-niolocker-exception-when-reading) discusses the challenges in using the nio FileLock.  But I'm not convinced my usage of the nio FileLock is faulty.  Instead, I'm suspicious that the mounted, networked file system I am reading from, which is read-only, presents problems for the nio FileLock.  The mount point for said file system looks like this:

```
/etc/auto.pathto on /pathto type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=6,pgrp=634173,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect,pipe_ino=2386182)
```

For now, I'm going to have to remove the nio FileLock because it's getting in the way rather than helping.  But is there some way to still get file-locking while reading a resource from a network, read-only file system?

```
22:01:53.262 [task-scheduler-2] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to lock file: /pathto/myfile.txt; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /pathto/myfile.txt (Read-only file system)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker.lock(NioFileLocker.java:54)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultDirectoryScanner.tryClaim(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:85)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.doReceive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:362)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.doReceive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:184)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:408)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:377)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$3(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:321)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /pathto/myfile.txt (Read-only file system)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:345)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:214)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.locking.FileChannelCache.tryLockFor(FileChannelCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker.lock(NioFileLocker.java:51)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: I believe the nio FileLock tries to write a ".lock" file or similar on the read-only file system, thus leading to the exception.  See article:  https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/4838.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption about read-only file system is probably correct.
At least I see that we have a logic in the `FileChannelCache` like:

```
FileChannel newChannel = new RandomAccessFile(fileToLock, "rw").getChannel();
```

So, we indeed fail here. And I believe eve if we set it only to `r`, we would fail further in the logic, e.g.:

```
public final FileLock tryLock() throws IOException {
    return tryLock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, false);
}
...
if (shared && !readable)
        throw new NonReadableChannelException();
if (!shared && !writable)
        throw new NonWritableChannelException();
```

Therefore a `NioFileLocker` is not for you.

You may implement your own `FileLocker`, but in most cases we just recommend to use a shared persistent `MetadataStore` and a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` for that File Inbound Channel Adapter. This way all the instance of your application are going to consult the same store and only one instance will process the file. All other instance will just skip it and move on to another one.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-reading

Comment: I decided to forgo file-locking altogether.  It doesn't sound like Linux supports it well -- unless, as you suggest, there is a coordinated locking strategy between processes.

Comment: That's correct: Linux does not offer an exclusive lock for files. Or you implement your own strategy, or use shared DB to have concurrent access and don't process the same file on different instances.